# Why does apply skip first element of array used for arguments?

Tags: javascript, constructor, apply

I am adding object literals to a prototype. I am doing this by taking the properties of objects and putting the values in an array. I am then creating a new object using the constructor, with the array as the arguments.

The only problem is that the constructor (using apply) is skipping the first element in the array when creating the new object, and so is assigning the wrong value to the wrong property in the new object - the last value ending up empty.

In the debugger, both the array and the constructor function display the properties/elements in the correct order. Yet the output is incorrect.

I know I could simply create the new objects by putting the arguments directly in the new object constructor. But this is difficult to read. Unless there is another way of attaching objects to a prototype? Or a tidier way of arranging my data, ready for the constructor?

Here is the code:

```js
(function(root, undefined) {
  var roomArray = [
    {
      locationIndex: 0,
      name: "North room",
      description: "The room is bare, there is a smashed window on the North wall, beyond which you see a grey mist.",
      exits: {north: false, south: 1, east: false, west: false, down: false, up: false}
    },
  {
      locationIndex: 1,
      name: "Room 1",
      description: "It is hard to see much here.",
      exits: {north: 0, south: 3, east: 2, west: false, down: false, up: false}
    },
    {
      locationIndex: 2,
      name: "Room 2",
      description: "A bedroom.",
      exits: {north: false, south: false, east: false, west: 1, down: false, up: false}
    },
    {
      locationIndex: 3,
      name: "kitchen",
      description: "A kitchen.",
      exits: {north: 1, south: false, east: false, west: false, down: false, up: false}
    }
  ];
  
  // Room constructor
    function Room(location, name, description, exits) {
      this.location = location;
      this.name = name;
      this.description = description;
      this.exits = exits;
  }
  
  // Create Rooms
  roomArray.forEach(function(room, index) {
    var convertArray = [];
    for (var props in room) {
      convertArray.push(room[props]);
    }
    eval("room_" + index + " = new (Room.bind.apply(Room, convertArray))()");
    console.log(convertArray);
    console.log(eval("room_" + index))
  });
  
})(this);
```

Comment: Why do you have a parameter to your function called `undefined`?

Comment: Old habit, it is just to ensure 'undefined' actually means 'undefined'. It's probably not even necessary, I just learned it that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
root['room_' + index] = new (Function.prototype.bind.apply(Room, convertArray))();
```

or for modern javascript

```
root['room_' + index] = new Room(...convertArray)
```

Comment: Thank you. That's definitely tidier. But the output is still wrong. The 'location' value should be a number. Same of the first element in the array I am applying to the constructor function.
Actually, the modern version fixes that problem, but strangely is not adding the index number to the variable name.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't reading it properly. The modern version is working perfectly. Thank you. I don't understand what was causing the problem in my version though.

Comment: though, the way you create `convertArray` isn't ideal

Comment: IS there a simpler way of doing the whole thing? I'm new at this, and I'm sure I'm missing a much simpler way of doing it.

Comment: `roomArray.forEach(({locationIndex, name, description, exits}, index) => root['room_' + index] = new Room(locationIndex, name, description, exits);`

Answer (score 1):

`Room.bind.apply(Room, convertArray)` is the issue. You are `apply`ing the `bind` function, not the constructor directly. Since bind takes `this` as the first parameter and so does `apply`, you've got to provide it twice.

Something like

```
Function.bind.apply(Room, [null].concat(convertArray))
```

should work.

[Relevant Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)

Comment: Ahh, thank you. I understand the problem now, was really confusing me. Thank you so much.